# How to extract element from HTML code in Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to webscrape multiple webpages of similar HTML code. I can already get the HTML of each page  and I can manually find the part of the code's string where the information I need is placed - I just don't know how to properly extract it. I believe my problem might be solved with REGEX, actually, but I don't know how.

I'm using Python 3

This is how I extract the page's HTML code:

```
import requests
resp = requests.get("https://statusinvest.com.br/fundos-imobiliarios/knri11",headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, features="html.parser")
```

Below is the string of the HTML code ( code -> str(soup) ). I want to extract the list between those two pink brackets. This block is always after the line between blue parenthesis (the text in green is different at each page)
[part of page's HTML code I want to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wat4U.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `beautifulsoup` to find the correct tag and `json` module to parse the values:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = requests.get(
    "https://statusinvest.com.br/fundos-imobiliarios/knri11",
    headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"},
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")

data = json.loads(soup.select_one("#results")["value"])

print(data)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {
        "y": 0,
        "m": 0,
        "d": 0,
        "ad": None,
        "ed": "31/10/2022",
        "pd": "16/11/2022",
        "et": "Rendimento",
        "etd": "Rendimento",
        "v": 0.91,
        "ov": None,
        "sv": "0,91000000",
        "sov": "-",
        "adj": False,
    },
    {
        "y": 0,
        "m": 0,
        "d": 0,
        "ad": None,
        "ed": "30/09/2022",
        "pd": "17/10/2022",
        "et": "Rendimento",
        "etd": "Rendimento",
        "v": 0.91,
        "ov": None,
        "sv": "0,91000000",
        "sov": "-",
        "adj": False,
    },


...and so on.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
import requests

resp = requests.get("https://statusinvest.com.br/fundos-imobiliarios/knri11", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, features="html.parser")
data = json.loads(soup.find("input", {"id": "results"}).get("value")
print(data)
```

To get the first value:

```
print(data[0]["y"])
```